# Encryption vs. digest

Tags: encryption, cryptography

What is the difference between encryption and a digest?

Answer (score 55):

Encryption takes a plain text and converts it to an encrypted text using a key and an encryption algorithm. The resulting encrypted text can later be decrypted (by using the same key and algorithm).

A digest takes a plain text and generates a hashcode which can be used to verify if the plain text is unmodified but *cannot* be used to decrypt the original text from the hash value.

Comment: Yes, digests are typically one-way, however with rainbow tables, or crappy hash algorithms it's possible to reverse the hash and get the original text. Just a minor point.

Comment: Nik, we should probably mention that nothing stops someone from changing the message and then generating a new digest.  Something like HMAC or DSA would do that, though.

Comment: @alan yes for short plaintexts like passwords, but not for big files like textdocuments or images

Comment: @Steven either that or you have to store the generated mac in a secure way/place

Comment: @Nik: Well, a good cryptographic digest is hard to find a plausible plaintext for on short order, so you could transmit the digest in the clear immediately prior to sending the plaintext in a private, but unencrypted and potentially tamperable, way.  For example, you could publish the digest in a newspaper and then send the plaintext by mail.  This doesn't prevent the mail from being intercepted, but it does make it hard to replace it with a fake message.

Comment: It occurs to me that I should probably mention that these are called preimage attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).  The type mentioned in my example would be a second preimage attack, at it has known plaintext.  As it stands, this is very difficult even with a "broken" hash like MD5, but it can be made arbitrarily more difficult simply by taking two different hashes.

Answer (score 6):

Encryption conceals the contents of the plaintext, while a digest is a special kind of hash that acts as a sort of fingerprint for the data. If the message digest is encrypted with a private key, this can be used as a digital signature to ensure that it came from a particular source.

Comment: Verifying the integrity of files can be done using a (message) digest, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_digest. However, authentication (i.e. verifying that a message comes from a particular source) can't be done using a simple digest. Authentication would require e.g. a digitial signature.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is the transformation of plaintext into ciphertext using a cryptographic function. A one-way cryptographic function such as a cryptographic hash function is irreversible. A two-way cryptographic function such as a symmetric or asymmetric key based function is reversible.

A message digest uses encryption to verify that the contents of a message aren’t modified in transit between the sender and receiver of the message. A message digest is a fixed-length string that is generated by applying a cryptographic hash function to the contents of an entire message. It is computed by the sender and attached to the message. When the receiver receives the message, the receiver can re-compute the message digest and compare it to the original message digest in the message. If the two strings are equal, the receiver can be sure that the message wasn’t altered in transit.

A message digest is also called a hash or fingerprint.